# /etc/hosts is not processed during boot

Tags: nfs, hosts, fstab

I have NFS mounts set up in `/etc/hstab` as

```
HOSTXYZ:/share/dir  /mnt/nfs/local-dir  nfs4    _netdev 0   0
```

It mounts fine when I run **`mount -a`** however it hangs during boot. I discovered that if I use IP address instead of `HOSTXYZ` it boots normally. `HOSTXYZ` is a local server defined in /etc/hosts. I am puzzled. Why doesn't it try to use `/etc/hosts` entries to resolve `HOSTXYZ` during boot?

`systemd` log indicates that it simply fails to mount when host name is used and a success when IP is used.

This occurs on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Since Ubuntu 16.04 ships with systemd you might check for boot errors with `journalctl -a`

Comment: a quick test to see if /etc/hosts works just ping the hostname and see if it resolves to the correct IP. nslookup will not work as it does a proper DNS lookup. --You could also mount by IP and see if you still have the issue

Comment: xguru, my question already explains that mounting by IP address works during boot and hosts file lookup works after boot.